# kubernetes: nginx ingress vs traefik ingress vs ha-proxy ingress vs kong ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, haproxy, traefik, kong-ingress

We are looking at various opensource ingress controllers available for kubernetes and need to chose the best one among all. We are evaluating the below four ingress controllers

1. Nginx ingress controller
2. Traefik ingress controller
3. Ha-proxy ingress controller
4. Kong ingress controller

What are the difference between these In terms of features and performance and which one should be adopted in production. please provide your suggestions

Comment: I am currently looking at traefik (version 2 supports TCP, is in alpha) after reading some comparisons such as this https://caylent.com/kubernetes-top-ingress-controllers/ and this one https://kubedex.com/ingress/ Traefik because it also supports rate limiting out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

One difference I’m aware of, is that haproxy and nginx ingresses can work in TCP mode, whereas traefik only works in HTTP/HTTPS modes. If you want to ingress services like SMTP or MQTT, then this is a useful distinction.

Also, haproxy supports the “PROXY” protocol, allowing you to pass real client IP to backend services. I used the haproxy ingress recently for a docker-mailserver helm chart - https://hub.helm.sh/charts/funkypenguin

Comment: Traefik has TCP and UDP routers. IP Forwarding is also a common feature